# Filling in time gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with a query that will fill in some missing time (in minutes) gaps, and also persist the current status.  I work in a hospital setting and we are trying to understand the bottlenecks in a hospital Emergency department, at any given minute.
The data in my table looks like this:

```
Patient_Id      event_time             Event_Status_Name
98676249    2018-09-24 18:39:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 19:17:00.000    Waiting for Triage
98676249    2018-09-24 19:28:00.000    In Triage
98676249    2018-09-24 19:29:00.000    Waiting for Room
98676249    2018-09-24 19:45:00.000    Waiting for Provider
98676249    2018-09-24 19:48:00.000    In Process
98676249    2018-09-24 21:02:00.000    Await IP Orders
98676249    2018-09-24 22:59:00.000    Await IP Bed
98676249    2018-09-25 21:44:00.000    Ready for Admit
```

This basically tells me at what time the patient entered a specific status.  What I need to do, however, is fill in the missing minutes, and persist the status that they are in.  As an example, from 2018-09-24 18:39:00.000 until 2018-09-24 19:16:00.000 the patient was in the "expected" status.  Just using the first status as an example, my desired query output would need to look like this:

```
Patient_Id  event_time             Event_Status_Name
98676249    2018-09-24 18:39:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:40:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:41:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:42:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:43:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:44:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:45:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:46:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:47:00.000    Expected
98676249    2018-09-24 18:48:00.000    Expected
```

etc, etc, until I hit the next status of "waiting for Triage"
...and then I'd need to do the same, for each minute of that status, until the next one...etc. etc.

How can I write query that does this, without using a loop?  There are millions of records (and minutes) to account for, so I need an inexpensive query for this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Would you consider adding an event_start_time & event_end_time?

Comment: sure.  but I'm thinking there would need to be a start and end time for each status?

Comment: google Gaps and Islands in TSQL.. like https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE here. As anchor get all the existing rows along with their row number ordered by the timestamp per patient. Then select the row from the anchor applying the next event to them -- via the row number and the patient -- and check, that the next minute is less than the succeeding event's timestamp.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT x.patient_id,
       x.event_time,
       x.event_status_name,
       x.rn
       FROM (SELECT t.patient_id,
                    t.event_time,
                    t.event_status_name,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.patient_id
                                       ORDER BY t.event_time) rn
                    FROM elbat t) x
UNION ALL
SELECT c.patient_id,
       dateadd(minute, 1, c.event_time),
       c.event_status_name,
       c.rn
       FROM cte c
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT y.patient_id,
                                y.event_time
                                FROM (SELECT t.patient_id,
                                             t.event_time,
                                             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.patient_id
                                                                ORDER BY t.event_time) rn
                                             FROM elbat t) y
                                     WHERE y.rn = c.rn + 1) x
        WHERE x.patient_id = c.patient_id
              AND x.event_time > dateadd(minute, 1, c.event_time)
)
SELECT *
       FROM cte c
       ORDER BY c.patient_id,
                c.event_time
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1364);
```

There is one problem though. Your gaps are so large, that the maximum recursion level of 100 is exceeded. You can enlarge it by using `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)`. To find a suitable `n`, you can query the data to find the maximum difference of subsequent events in minutes. Again this uses `row_number()` to map succeeding events. Take that maximum minus one for the maximum recursion level.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT t.patient_id,
       t.event_time,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.patient_id
                          ORDER BY event_time) rn
       FROM elbat t
)
SELECT max(datediff(minute, c2.event_time, c1.event_time)) - 1
       FROM cte c1
            INNER JOIN cte c2
                       ON c2.patient_id = c1.patient_id
                          AND c2.rn = c1.rn - 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=0a3214b0d4cee4df114310aed2cfc126)

Comment: This is great, thanks.  But I'm having a problem with the recursion.  Even at the max setting of 32767, my data is exceeding it, failing.

Comment: @JameyJameson: Well, as you said, this is about emergency in a hospital and the last step in your example takes about a day, I guess this is already out of the emergency situation? Maybe you can just filter out the last step (or even steps) if they aren't relevant and the ones that produce that large gaps?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think inserting those minutes would make your millions of rows much more millions of rows with a lot of redundant data in it? What could be the purpose? (Maybe some kind of display related work?).

Anyway, if you think you have to, then you could do that with some cross apply. ie:

```
WITH tally
AS (SELECT TOP (1440 * 10)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) AS N
    FROM master.sys.all_columns t1
        CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2),
     missedMinutes
AS (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Patients t1
        CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.event_time, MIN(t2.event_time))
        FROM Patients t2
        WHERE t1.Patient_Id = t2.Patient_Id
              AND t2.event_time > t1.event_time
    ) t(missed)
        CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(missed, 1) - 1)
               DATEADD(MINUTE, N, t1.event_time)
        FROM dbo.Patients t2
            CROSS JOIN tally
        WHERE t2.Patient_Id = t1.Patient_Id
              AND t1.event_time = t2.event_time
        ORDER BY tally.N
    ) tt(missing) )
SELECT Patient_Id,
       missing AS event_time,
       Event_Status_Name
INTO #missInsert
FROM missedMinutes
ORDER BY event_time;

SELECT *
FROM #missInsert;

DROP TABLE #missInsert;
```

[DBFiddle Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25821868bad824f3355d562383889a88)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for putting this together.  And yes, adding the missing minutes is adding millions of additional records.  But there is a need to understand total volume and throughput, at any given minute of the day, through the use of multiple heat map visualization tools.  So I either have to build the logic to find patients and statuses through the visualization tool, or I have to create the gap records in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @calc1 as table (Paitent_event_sno int,Patient_Id int, event_time DateTime,Event_Status_Name varchar(100))                                      
insert into @calc1 Select Paitent_event_sno = ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by Patient_Id order by event_time Asc), *  from @Hospital 
Declare @final as table (Patient_Id int, event_time DateTime,Event_Status_Name varchar(100))

Declare @Pno int, @Sno int
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for 
Select Distinct Patient_id from @calc1
open cur
fetch next from cur into @Pno
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

declare cur2 CURSOR LOCAL for 
Select Distinct Paitent_event_sno from @calc1  where  Patient_Id =  @Pno 
open cur2
fetch next from cur2 into @Sno
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

        declare @starttime datetime , @endtime datetime, @eventtime datetime
        insert into @final
        Select Patient_Id, event_time , Event_Status_Name from @calc1 
        where Patient_Id =   @Pno and   Paitent_event_sno = @Sno

        Select @starttime = event_time , @eventtime = event_time from  @calc1 where Patient_Id =   @Pno and   Paitent_event_sno = @Sno

        Select @endtime = event_time from @calc1 where Patient_Id =   @Pno and   Paitent_event_sno = @Sno+1


        set @eventtime = dateadd(mi,1,@eventtime )

        while @eventtime < @Endtime
        begin
        insert into @final
        Select Patient_Id,  @eventtime,Event_Status_Name   
        from @calc1 where Patient_Id =   @Pno and   
        Paitent_event_sno = @Sno

        set @eventtime = dateadd(mi,1,@eventtime )
        end                    

        fetch next from cur2 into @Sno
        END
        close cur2
        deallocate cur2

        fetch next from cur into @pno
        END
        close cur
        deallocate cur

        Select * from @final
```